# I get an extra input space when I run my code

Tags: java

I run my code then I put in an integer, press enter, then I get an extra input space. In the extra input space I put in a number then I get the input space I want where it says "Write A Line". It only adds the numbers I put in the first input space and the extra input space. Please help. (P.S Sorry for code's format)

My Output:
Write An Integer
(put my input here)
(put my input here)
Write An Integer
(put my input here)

I don't want that 2nd input option.

```
public static void main(String eth[]){

System.out.println("Write An Integer");
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


if (input.hasNextInt()){
}
else System.out.println("Play By The Rules");
Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = input1.nextInt();
{

System.out.println("Write An Integer");
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
int b = input2.nextInt();

int answer = (a+b); 
System.out.println(answer);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to add two numbers?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to add 2 numbers.

Comment: is this the result that you want? `Write An Integer (put my input here)Write An Integer (put my input here)`

Comment: @DyrandzFamador Yes.

Comment: you have a problem on your bracket.. check it again.. also use bracket on `else`, by default, if you don't put a bracket it will just execute one statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra space you're getting is from a logical error in first `if` statement. If `input.hasNextInt()` is true, then it will skip over `else` but call the `Scanner`  directly below because it is not grouped with the `else` statement. Also, this only allows for two attempts for `input1` and one for `input2`. Therefore, I'd switch to a `while` loop for each and create a method to read in integers instead of duplicating code.

```
public static void main(String eth[]) {
    int a = readInt();
    int b = readInt();
    int answer = (a + b);
    System.out.println(answer);
}
private static int readInt() {
    System.out.println("Write An Integer");
    Scanner input = null;
    while(!(input = new Scanner(System.in)).hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println("Play By The Rules, Write An Integer");
    }
    return input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are trying to add two numbers with strings in between, a better way to do it would be,

```
Scanner sr=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Play By The Rules")
int a=sr.nextInt();
System.out.println("Write An Integer");
int b = sr.nextInt();
int answer = (a+b);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use single instance for 
>   Scanner and make sure close the scanner input after operation
>
> Refer code below

```
public static void main(String eth[]) {

    System.out.println("Write An Integer");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    } else
        System.out.println("Play By The Rules");

    int a = input.nextInt();
    {
        System.out.println("Write An Integer");
        int b = input.nextInt();
        int answer = (a + b);
        System.out.println(answer);
        input.close();
    }
}
```